# Where is the delete button?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook

Where is the delete button or is there only the backspace button?

Mac newbie here!  Loving it though!  How will I ever go back to windows :)

Comment: *»How will I ever go back to windows?«* – Simple. By installing Windows again (and attaching a proper mouse) :-þ

Comment: I will only use Windows again if I am obligated to at work...otherwise I am now completely Mac converted :)

Comment: @thelearner: except for the keyboard :), @Johannes Rössel: hehe.

Comment: hehe yeah baby steps

Comment: I connect my 15" MacBook Pro to an external keyboard, mouse and 22" monitor when I'm in my office. I get a delete key, dedicated media control keys (in addition to the function keys), multiple buttons on my mouse and a ergonomically positioned display. I love my macbook (*and* its trackpad), but I think full sized peripherals are the way to go when feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete is fn-backspace if you only have native backspace key.

Answer (score 0):

A drawback of the MacBook. However I use an open-source add-on called DoubleCommand. It allows you to remap your keyboard, e.g. mapping the right-option key as Delete (as I've done). Works as it should.

Find it on SourceForge.

--NYC Larry

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other approaches, Mac OS these days has support for some Emacs-style keybindings, so `control-D` is also forward-delete.